# solving conditional symbolic equation in R

Tags: r

Here are my vectors. Note that the vector `m` consists of unknown value `x`.

```
r=c(1, 3, 5)

p=c(5, 3, 1)

s=c(1, 3, 5)

m=c(x, x, x)
```

How I can solve the following conditional vector equation in R?
I'd like to find the value of x which makes the sum of elements in the vector of `p*(s-m)*(ifelse((s-m)<0, r, 6-r))` zero.

```
sum(p*(s-m)*(ifelse((s-m)<0, r, 6-r)))=0
```

I was told that `rSymPy` might handle this but I don't think this works for the vector equation. Any thoughts or suggestions?

In fact, I was able to get the answer in Excel using "goal seek" but would like to get R commands for solving this.

Comment: Welcome to our site - this kind of coding question is off-topic here (have a look at our [help/on-topic]) but it seems to me to be a suitable question for Stack Overflow. If others agree with me, then this can be migrated there for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel does numeric calculations, not symbolic, so we assume that a numeric solution is really what you want.  In that case it can be solved numerically like this:

```
f <- function(x) sum(p*(s-x)*(ifelse((s-x)<0, r, 6-r)))^2
optimize(f, range(s))
```

giving:

```
$minimum
[1] 2.4667

$objective
[1] 3.1554e-30
```

Comment: That is really helpful. The result I get with your suggested code is equal to what I get from Excel. Thank you very much!